# Vuejs Module Federation dynamic import

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, webpack-5, dynamic-import, webpack-module-federation

I'm trying to develop microfrontend with Vuejs and Module Federation. So, i have method loadModule, that returns me a an object(maybe component), but what i should do with it i don't know. I tried to import this component like *defineAsyncComponent* but it's useless.

And i'm tried use the render function in this object and paste this it to markup.
The screenshot shows what the object I get, but I don’t know what to do next with it and how to register this like component.

I'm stumped, any advice would be welcome

```
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted, defineAsyncComponent, h } from 'vue'

import TestComp from './TestComp.vue'
let Header
const modules = [
  {
    protocol: 'http',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 8080,
    moduleName: 'Company',
    fileName: 'remoteEntry.js',
    componentNames: ['Header'],
  },
]

onMounted(() => {
  modules.forEach((uiApplication) => {
    const remoteURL = `${uiApplication.protocol}://${uiApplication.host}:${uiApplication.port}/${uiApplication.fileName}`

    const { componentNames } = uiApplication
    const { moduleName } = uiApplication
    const element = document.createElement('script')
    element.type = 'text/javascript'
    element.async = true
    element.src = remoteURL

    element.onload = () => {
      componentNames?.forEach((componentName) => {
        const component = loadComponent(moduleName, `./${componentName}`)

        component().then((res) => {
          Header = res
          console.log(res)
          // what should i do next?

          // This is not working
          // Header = defineAsyncComponent(() => import('Company/Header'))
        })
      })
    }
    document.head.appendChild(element)
  })
})[enter image description here][1]


function loadComponent(scope, module) {
  return async () => {
    // Initializes the shared scope. Fills it with known provided modules from this build and all remotes
    await __webpack_init_sharing__('default')
    const container = window[scope] // or get the container somewhere else
    // Initialize the container, it may provide shared modules
    await container.init(__webpack_share_scopes__.default)
    const factory = await window[scope].get(module)
    const Module = factory()
    return Module
  }
}
const remoteImport = async (location, name, options) => {
  const module = await importResource(location, options)
  if (name) {
    let m = module[name]
    if (!m) {
      throw new Error(
        `No component named ${name} founded in component ${location}`
      )
    }
    return module[name]
  } else {
    return module
  }
}
</script>
<template>
  <div>
    <Header ref="Header" title="Test shop" />
    <h2>Our Shop Page</h2>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: You're using Vue3 here? If it's the case, maybe give a try to Vite's module federation. It may be easier to setup.